# How to add parent function to KnockOut double-nested mapping?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using KnockOut mapping fromJS to create my View Model from a JSON object like the following:

```
{
    "cats": [{
        "name": "fluffy",
        "color": "brown",
        "kittens": [{
            "name": "spot",
            "color": "brown"
        }, {
            "name": "rascal",
            "color": "grey"
        }, {
            "name": "trouble",
            "color": "white"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "kitty",
        "color": "red",
        "kittens": [{
            "name": "lady",
            "color": "red"
        }, {
            "name": "skat",
            "color": "striped"
        }]
    }]
}
```

**html:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach:cats">
    <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
    <table>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: kittens">
             <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
             <td data-bind="text:color"></td>
             <td><a data-bind="click: $parent:showParentColor" href="#">Parent Color</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var KittenModel = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    // ... various computed values added to this
}

var mapping = {
    'kittens': {
        create: function(options) {
            return new KittenModel(options.data);
        }
    },
    'otherItem': {
        create: function(options) {
             return ('otherStuff');
        }
     }
}

var data = { ... }; // the JSON above

var CatsViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

**Question:**

Where and how do I put the showParentColor() function so that the the data-bind works in the kitten table? For example:

```
function showParentColor(cat) {
    alert(cat.color);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use one of the following based on your view model hierarchy :

- **$root** :  This points to the main view model object in the root context.The top most parent context.
- **$parents array :** This is an array which contains all your view models.

  - **$parents[0] :** The parent view model context.(also it’s the same as `$parent`)
  - **$parents[1]:**  The  second parent view model context.(grand parent)
  - **$parents[2]:** The third parent view model context . (great-grand parent)
  - **And so on....**

**Update :** 
If you want to add a function in `CatsViewModel` level, you simply add your function to created model.

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/87/

JS:

```
 CatsViewModel.showParentColor = function(item){
      console.log(item.name());
      console.log(item.color());
    }
```

View:

```
<a data-bind="click: $parents[1].showParentColor">
```

Below is the hierarchy of your model

```
- CatsViewModel 
    - cats : observableArray
        - name : observable
        - color : observable
        - kittens : observableArray
               - name : observable
               - color : observable
    - showParentColor : function
```

---

**Alternative :** You can do the job yourself and create your models.Would be easier for you to modify and maintain based on what you want.You can also add  `click` function inside any models you want.

Example :http://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/91/

**HTML :**

```
<div data-bind="foreach:cats">
    <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
    <table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: kittens">
       <tr>
             <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
             <td data-bind="text:color"></td>
             <td><a data-bind="click: $parent.showParentColor" href="#">Parent Color</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 var data = {
    "cats": [{
        "name": "fluffy",
        "color": "brown",
        "kittens": [{
            "name": "spot",
            "color": "brown"
        }, {
            "name": "rascal",
            "color": "grey"
        }, {
            "name": "trouble",
            "color": "white"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "kitty",
        "color": "red",
        "kittens": [{
            "name": "lady",
            "color": "red"
        }, {
            "name": "skat",
            "color": "striped"
        }]
    }]
}

var CatsViewModel = function (data){ 
  var self = this;
  self.cats = ko.observableArray($.map(data.cats, function (item) {
        return new CatItemViewModel(item);
    }));
}
var CatItemViewModel = function (data){
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.color = ko.observable(data.color);
  self.kittens = ko.observableArray($.map(data.kittens, function (item)     {
   var newData = Object.assign({}, item, { parent: self.name()});
        return new KittenModel(newData);
   }));
   self.showParentColor = function (item){
      console.log("Parent Name: " , self.name());
      console.log("Name: " , item.name());
      console.log("Color: " , item.color());
   }
}
var KittenModel = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.color = ko.observable(data.color);
  self.parent = ko.observable(data.parent);
}
var vm = new CatsViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using $parent (or $parents[0]) in my example because I want to call a function on the 'cat' object from the 'kitten' object. What I don't understand is how to put that function in the 'cat' object via the mapping parameter.

Comment: So I had tried that but didn't understand why adding the function to the CatsViewModel required me to bind it with $parents[1] (or $root) instead of $parents[0] (or $parent). I figured it was in the parent of the kitten, not the grandparent! Can you explain?

Comment: Thanks for the Example. However, it logs the name and color of the kitten instead of the cat! (This would have been more obvious if the cats and kittens had different attributes.) Secondly, if we add the method to the CatsViewModel, how does it know which cat is being referenced?

Comment: Take look at updated example. If your cats names are `unique` you can add the parent to `kittens` data while it's mapping and then inside click function you know which parent it is.

Comment: Well that *does* work (similar to user3297291's Alternative 2), but is there a way to add a method to each 'cat' object that can be referenced in a 'kitten' object by $parent? I thought that was the whole point of using $parent, $parents[], and $root properties in KnockOut foreach loops. Thanks again for your time on this!

Comment: Look at the alternative answer. It might help you understand better.

Comment: The problem with that alternative is that it copied the parent's name into the kitten object via Object.assign() rather than referencing it directly in the ShowParentColor method. However, I was able to use your example to figure out how to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/91/. I learned a lot about KnockOut, especially that the 'mapping' extension couldn't do all I wanted and it was better to create the View Model from scratch as you showed me. Check it out, and thanks again.

Comment: Yes. using `self.name()` is referencing directly to the parent name and definitely increasing the performance.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I like the other answer's approach better than this one, but did want to present an alternative solution for the sake of having multiple options.*

### Alternative 1

You could create a "static" method in your `KittenModel` that logs any cat's color that it's passed:

```
var KittenModel = function (data) {
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};

KittenModel.logCatColor = function(cat) {
  console.log(cat.color);
};
```

Now, because your view has access to the parent-child structure, you can call this method with any parent you want:

```
<!-- to log the parent's color -->
<div data-bind="click: logCatColor.bind(null, $parent)"></div>

<!-- knockout automatically passes `$data` as a first argument,
     so you won't need to bind the method to log your own color -->
<div data-bind="click: logCatColor"></div>
```

An example:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  name: "parent",
  child: {
    name: "child",
    logName: function(entity) {
      console.log(entity.name);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
<div data-bind="with: child" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <h2 data-bind="text: name">
    </h2>
  <button data-bind="click: logName">
    log my name
  </button>
  <button data-bind="click: logName.bind(null, $parent)">
    log my parent's name
  </button>
</div>
```

### Alternative 2

In the factory function you're passing as an options, you have both `data` and `parent` available: `options.data` holds the item being currently mapped. `options.parent` in this case will refer to the parent `cat`. I haven't tested this, but this might work:

```
'kittens': {
    create: function(options) {
        var dataWithParent = Object.assign({}, 
                               options.data, 
                               { parent: options.parent });

        return new KittenModel(dataWithParent);
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting approach that works. I haven't seen the bind method until now. Per Mozzilla: "The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called." However, passing the 'cat' to a 'kitten' function doesn't really feel right to me since the kitten should be "aware" of its parent, no?

Comment: I guess that depends on whether you need a kitten to be aware of its parent... You could say that `CatsViewModel` is in charge of the relations between `CatModel` and `KittenModel` instances. Storing these references inside the models would be a duplication of this data. *However*, in practice, it can of course be quite useful to have easy access to parents and children.

Comment: @ScottyB I've included a second alternative that might be a bit closer to the mapping library and your initial intentions.