# Access element that has KO click binding to remove parent element from DOM

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have created some code that when a user clicks an element creates a small popover window. Several of these elements exist and each creates their own window when clicked.

This is the HTML that is being created:

```
<div class="window">
  <header>
    <h2 class="title" data-bind="text: title">window title</h2>
    <i data-bind="click: destroyWindow(this)">close</i>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="content">content area</div>
  </main>
</div>
```

When I click on that "close" element, I want to remove the whole window from the DOM entirely.

My idea was to go like this in the corresponding viewmodel:

```
self.destroyWindow = function(elem) {
    $(elem).closest('.window').remove();
};
```

but it seems I cannot pass the element that was clicked on as a parameter that easily. `console.log(elem)` revealed that `this` pointed to the global object `window`.

This is the complete viewmodel `../component/draggable.window.js`:

```
var WindowViewModel = function (params) {
    var self = this;
    /* BEGIN Properties */
    self.title = ko.observable("Window title");
    self.destroyWindow = function(elem) {
        $(elem).closest('.window').remove();
    };
    /* END Properties */
};
```

This is the call that adds these windows to the DOM:

```
var dragWin = require('../component/draggable.window.html'); // the above html
var vm = require('../component/draggable.window');
$(dragWin)
    .appendTo($("body"))
    .applyBindings(new vm())
;
```

I have also written a very small jQuery plugin that applies the bindings to a dynamically generated DOM element:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.applyBindings = function(vm) {
        return this.each(function() {
            ko.applyBindings(vm ? vm : null, this);
        });
    };
}(jquery));
```

#### Question: What would be the correct way to remove that window from the DOM when someone clicks "close"?

P.S.: I know I could write an inline onclick handler such as

```
<i onclick="$(this).closest('.window').remove()">close</i>
```

but this is a) not KO way and b) very unelegant.

Comment: You can try with `$elment` http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html : `<i data-bind="click: destroyWindow($elment)">close</i>`

Comment: Thx for that hint, will try that right tomorrow at work!

Comment: imo, the true knockout approach would be to create an observable `isWindowOpen` and then use `if: isWindowOpen` in `<div class="window">`, with that, the click binding would simply set `isWindowOpen` to false

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a simpler way in pure `knockout`.

- Have an observable array which holds element of your windows.
- Have a window View Model and create a new instance for every new window and push it to the array (no need to have a dynamic binding).
- Remove a corresponding window by passing it to the parent model.
- You can also have a variable for `css` binding inside your WindowVM to give a different style to each window.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/150/

**JS:**

```
var MainViewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.windowList = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.destroyWindow = function(item){
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.windowList(), function (element) {
      if(element && element == item)self.windowList.remove(element);
    });
   }
  var i = 0;
  self.createWindow = function(){
    i++;
    self.windowList.push(new WindowViewModel ({title: "Window " + i , content : " content area " + i }));
  }
}        

var WindowViewModel = function(data){
  var self = this;
  self.title = ko.observable(data.title || '');
  self.content = ko.observable(data.content || '');
}

var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**View:**

```
<!-- ko foreach: windowList -->
<div  class="modal">
  <div class="window">
    <h2 class="title" data-bind="text: title">window title</h2>
   <button class="close" data-bind="click: $parent.destroyWindow">X </button>
   <p class="content" data-bind="text: content"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I got most of the stuff working. I have a `<window-manager>` component that creates `<draggable-window>` components inside, so it's a nested relation. How can I call `windowManager.destroyWindow` from inside my `draggable-window` component? `$parent.destroyWindow` will apparently not work.

Comment: Use $parents array with index to access it. Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/39969391/6106583

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for not reusing much of your code, but I'd like to point out that doing this "the KO way" might be even more different from "the jQuery way" than you'd expect.

Usually, if you want to dynamically add and remove a DOM element, you use either the `if`, `visible` or `with` binding. The `if` and `with` bindings remove their child elements when they are given a "falsy" value. The `visible` binding *hides* its contents when falsy.

For a popup/modal like approach, you'd do something like:

- There's an `App` that has one `window` observable.
- Several of the app's component have access to this observable; they can put a view model in there
- In the UI, there's a container that checks if there's "something" in `window`, if there is: it renders a modal
- To close the modal, we clear its value: `this.window(null)`

```js
var Button = function(label, info, window) {
  this.label = label;
  this.info = info;
  
  // On click, we pass this viewmodel to window
  this.onClick = window;
};
    
var App = function() { 
  this.window = ko.observable(null);

  this.closeWindow = function() {
    this.window(null);
  }.bind(this);

  // Give our button access to our window
  this.myButton = new Button("Button 1", 
                             "Info about this button", 
                             this.window);
};

ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```css
.window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h2>App</h2>
  <div data-bind="with: myButton">
    <button data-bind="text: label, click: onClick"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ko with: window -->
<div class="window">
  <button data-bind="click: $parent.closeWindow">close</button>
  <p data-bind="text: info"></p>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

*After comment expressing concern that this would not work for multiple windows*: Let's make `window` an `observableArray`. An `openWindow` function modifies the data it gets, adds a `close` method and `pos` (for the sake of the example), and pushes it to the array.

```js
var Button = function(label, info, openWindowCB) {
  this.label = label;
  this.info = info;
  
  // On click, we pass this viewmodel to window
  this.onClick = openWindowCB;
};
    
var App = function() { 
  this.windows = ko.observableArray([]);

  this.hasWindows = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return !!this.windows().length;
  }, this);
    
  
  this.closeWindow = function(window) {
    this.windows.remove(window);
  }.bind(this);
  
  this.openWindow = function(vm) {
    // Here, you *could* compose a window by adding a close, drag, etc. method:
    // Can be by wrapping in another VM, or by adding functions:
    var windowVM = {};
    var index = this.myButtons.indexOf(vm);
    var extension = {
      close: this.closeWindow.bind(this, windowVM),
      pos: { left: index * 50 + "px", top: index * 20 + "px" }
    };
    
    Object.assign(windowVM, vm, extension);
    
    this.windows.push(windowVM);
  }.bind(this);

  // Give our button access to our window
  this.myButtons = [1,2,3,4,5].map(function(id) {
    return new Button("Button  " + id, 
                      "Info about button " + id,
                      this.openWindow);
    
  }.bind(this));
};

ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```css
.windows {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.window {
  position: absolute;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid black;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  <h2>App</h2>
  <div data-bind="foreach: myButtons">
    <button data-bind="text: label, click: onClick"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ko if: hasWindows -->
<div class="windows" data-bind="foreach: windows">
  <div class="window" data-bind="style: pos" >
    <button data-bind="click: close">close</button>
    <p data-bind="text: info"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I'd agrre if the use-case were singleton, but it's not. There can be many open windows in parallel and each one needs its own close handler. I also implemented a true overlay in the fashion you're suggesting.

Comment: Doesn't really change the main point: don't alter the DOM without knockout, minimise manually re-applying bindings. You can have a `WindowManager` class  that has an array of windows. Use `template` bindings to render their contents, use composition to add window functionality to your viewmodels...

Comment: What is "composition" in this context? Also, your new suggestion sounds like it is very different from the answer you gave.

Comment: I'll add another example to show what I mean... Considering "sounds like its very different": The main intent of my answer was to show you that with some default bindings and observables you can solve the whole problem of dynamically *adding*, *binding* and *removing* DOM content. It sounded like you have enough js knowledge to handle the stuff not related to the specifics of the knockout library.

Comment: Again: What is "composition" in this context? I've never heard the term in conjunction with programming. Aside from that, thanks for taking the time!

Comment: In a problem like this, there's the concept of *"The ability to render inside a window"*. In practice, this means you'll need a few utility functions, like a `closeWindow` method. By "composing" I mean that you can *add* these capabilities to *any* viewmodel. If you define the methods and properties your window expects, you can bake those requirements into any other model. It's a bit abstract, but I hope the example in the answer makes it more tangible...

Comment: Would using an observable array mean that every time I open or close a window all other windows will be re-drawn?

Comment: Nope, knockout takes care of that for you when you use `push` or `remove`. You can see its behaviour by going to your developer tools and toggling "Paint Flashing" (I'm using Chrome).